# Adding Facebook login to existing Spring Security project

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have an existing project that is secured with spring security (authentication from db). I would like to add an option that would allow user to login using facebook. I googled it out and tried on my own but got stuck. Generally the idea is that once user has confirmed the identity via the facebook the rest will be handled by my "UserDetailsService" which will load additional data from db (id, etc...).
If you could point me on what to do I would appreciate it much.

Here is some code:

**Security Config:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    CustomSuccessHandler customSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("superuser").password("override").roles("ADMIN");
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // added to handle local characters
        CharacterEncodingFilter filter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        filter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        filter.setForceEncoding(true);

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/index").permitAll().antMatchers("/Admin/**")
                .access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
                .antMatchers("/Customer/**")
                .access("hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('USER')")
                .antMatchers("/User/**")
                .access("hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('USER')")
                .and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").usernameParameter("email").passwordParameter("password").loginPage("/login")
                .successHandler(customSuccessHandler).and().csrf().and().formLogin().and().exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/403");

    }
}
```

**My implementation of UserDetailsService:**

```
@Component
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeService service;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        Employee employee = service.loadByMail(email);
        if (employee == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found");
        }

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + employee.getRole()));
        MyUser myUser = new MyUser(employee.getFullName(), employee.getPassword(), employee.getEmail(),
                employee.getId(), employee.getStatus().equals("AKTYWNY"), true, true, true, authorities);

        return myUser;
    }


}
```

**Finally the Extended User class:**

```
public class MyUser extends User {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long id;
    private String mail;
    public MyUser(String username, String password, String mail, Long id, boolean enabled, boolean accountNonExpired,
            boolean credentialsNonExpired, boolean accountNonLocked,
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);
        this.id = id;
        this.mail = mail;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyUser [id=" + id + ", mail=" + mail + "]";
    }
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }
    public void setMail(String mail) {
        this.mail = mail;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Spring Social Facebook](http://projects.spring.io/spring-social-facebook/)